# Show that we have an algebra homomrohpsim

Tags: representation-theory, modules, tensor-products, algebras

I need to show that we have an algebra homomorphism $\phi: M_n(K)\otimes_KA \simeq M_n(A)$ Where A is a K-algebra and K is some field.

I suspect it's really easy but I don't know what to do. Is $\phi$ the homomorphism that sends each entry $(k_{ij})$ of $M_n(K)$ to $k_{ij}a$ or something?

Comment: That seems like a fine plan. What problem do you have showing it is an isomorpism?

Comment: I assume you mean to say that it sends $\left(k_{ij}\right)_{i,j} \otimes a$ to $\left(k_{ij}a\right)_{i,j}$. Then, it's right.

Comment: Apologies. Yes, that's what I meant.

So, I define like above (and extend linearly obviously). Surjectivity follows because we can just consider matrices with all entries 0 apart from entry (i,j) which is 1, tensored with whatever we want. Is the easiest way to show injectivity to show that the kernel is trivial?

Comment: You can use the fact that if u forget about algebra structure and u consider only $k$ vector space structure u see that dimensions agree and u need only surjectivity.